# How I add circle on circle with cutting layer?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, subclass, geometry

I mean that I have custom view with one big circle and one smaller. But how I could cut corner (layer) of a big circle? Background is from parent view, not from custom, which have a clear color.

[image]

Icon, name label and label notifications I have been added in my custom view. So, problem still here with two intersecting circles.

Comment: Although you could achieve this effect with [boolean operations](http://losingfight.com/blog/2011/07/07/how-to-implement-boolean-operations-on-bezier-paths-part-1/), a simpler solution might be to give a stroke (that matches your background color) to your smaller circle and bring it to front.

Comment: "Icon, name label and label notifications I have been added in my custom view." A lot depends on how you are doing that. But basically this is not a layer problem. It's just a drawing problem. In the corner, draw a bigger white circle in front of the central circle; then draw a smaller green circle. - Alternatively, use the bigger corner circle as a clipping area when you draw the central circle.

Comment: Alternatively, use a clear blend mode to "erase" the larger corner circle before drawing the smaller corner circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've suggested three approaches in my comments above. Here's a demonstration of one of them. Note that I didn't really do the math or try to approximate your drawing: it's just a demonstration of the principle:

[image]

That's actually three circles:

- The big central circle (green) at lower left
- The larger corner circle, used to "erase" the top right corner of the first circle
- The second, smaller corner circle (green) at top left

Here's the code that generated that drawing (ignore the numbers; it's the principle that's important):

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(0,rect.height-130-10,130,130))

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
CGContextSetBlendMode(con, kCGBlendModeClear) // erase
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(rect.width-65, -5, 70, 70))

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(con, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor)
CGContextSetBlendMode(con, kCGBlendModeNormal)
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(rect.width-53,3,50,50))
```

Comment: Yep! Exactly what I need. I have one question about it:) So, I draw these circles in drawRect method, but how I could to pass my color or get access to small and big circles in next. I need animation for each of them...